# Get trait name and generic parameters for ItemImpl with syn

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I have a code like this:

```
#[my_attribute]
impl<T> Foo<T> for Bar where T: Baz { ... }
```

How to get the `Foo<T>` part from `ItemImpl`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The `trait_` field of `ItemImpl`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.50/syn/struct.ItemImpl.html#structfield.trait_) contains the information you are interested in

```rust
trait_: Option<(Option<Bang>, Path, For)>
```

It's an `Option` as impl blocks don't have to implement a trait (e.g. `impl Baz { }`). From the inner three-tuple, you are intersted in the second item, the [`Path`](https://docs.rs/syn/1.0.50/syn/struct.Path.html). That contains your `Foo<T>`.

Comment: Thanks, already found it. If anyone is interested, the code looks like this: `&trait_def.trait_.as_ref().unwrap().1`